# Directinput start effect with duration

Tags: c++, directx, directinput, force-feedback

I got this issue:

when I create my periodic effect I set

`jsInfo.periodic[p].effect.dwDuration = INFINITE;`

'cause I don't know what will be the duration...

after, when I need to play the effect *(and I know the duration)* I do this:

```
...
jsInfo.periodic[p].effect.dwDuration = duration * 1000;
...
HRESULT hr = jsInfo.periodic[p].pEffect->SetParameters(&jsInfo.periodic[periodic].effect, DIEP_DIRECTION | DIEP_TYPESPECIFICPARAMS | DIEP_START);
jsInfo.periodic[p].pEffect->Start(1, 0);
```

and the effect works fine, but can't stop it...

otherwise, if during creation I put 5 seconds, it works..

any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: What device are you using that supports legacy DirectInput force-feedback?

Comment: I'm working on g29